# What is the fastest way to compress image to a specified size?

Tags: android, image-compression

In my project, I need to upload some images(1-10) to server sometimes. The size varies from 1M to 10M. Before upload,each image should be compressed until size<512KB. I do the compression like this:

```
public static byte[] compressImageA(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int options = 100;
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, options, baos);
    while (baos.size() / 1024 > maxSize) {
        baos.reset();
        options -= 10;
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, options, baos);
    }
    if (image != null && !image.isRecycled()) {
        try {
            image.recycle();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

This method can make it, but not fast enough.For example,it takes about 25 seconds to compress 10 images.(Size of each is between 1M and 10M).After some tests,I find `Bitmap.compress()` may be called many times and takes the most time during a compression.So what can I do to make it faster? I want `Bitmap.compress()` to be called only 1 time during each compression.Or is there any other way to compress image to a specified size more faster？

Comment: Did you find the solution for it?

Comment: @PPV Unfortunately. nope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to reduce size from actual size

```
/**
     * reduces the size of the image
     *
     * @param image  uncompressed image
     * @param reduce how much to reduce
     * @return new bitmap
     */
    public static Bitmap reduceBitmap(Bitmap image, int reduce) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width -= reduce;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height -= reduce;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }
        if (width > 0 && height > 0)
            return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
        else
            return image;
    }
```

or You can use below codes according to your need, I am using it for **PNG** your can check for other

```
Bitmap actualImage=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("imagg1.png"));
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
actualImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Your algorithm is about as fast as it gets.

Time to start thinking outside the box. 10 images in 25s means 1 image takes 2.5s. How fast do you want it to be? Luckily, the algorithm is easily parallelizable. So you could split the task across n computers.

Comment: the guy needs an algorithm, not the explanation. And how do you suppose to parallel it arcoss n android phones?